# Java Playwright get Siblings by ElementHandle

Tags: java, playwright, headless, headless-browser

I have a page with i select the items but i need starting with a ElementHandle i need to get the N next siblings this cannot be make with a general css selector the info i need is in the siblings i have try the following but i doesn't work.

```
elementHandle.evaluateHandle("(element)=>element?.nextSibling.nextSibling").asElement()
elementHandle.getProperty("nextSibling").getProperty("nextSibling").asElement().innerHTML()
```

But both im receiving is a empty String

[image]
[image]

All i want from a ElementHandle get the next sibling like in JSoup

```
element.nextElementSibling()
```

I have tried but with not success.

Comment: Maybe https://playwright.dev/java/docs/other-locators#css-pick-n-th-match-from-the-query-result can help?

Comment: Without the site, the page's markup and a [mcve] of the code, there's no real way to debug this.

Comment: All i want is from a ElementHandle get the sibling that's all.